# I have 2 command buttons in current worksheet, both are codded, I require the correct coding

Tags: excel, vba

I am new to VBA so very little experience. I have created 2 command buttons with basic coding. The reason for 2 command buttons is the coloring of font. If command button 1 is clicked the font will be black (visible on the sheet and editable), if command button 2 is clicked the font will tun to white (invisible) when printing the report. I have copied the code below to have this done and everything is working fine. When a copy and move the sheet in the same workbook the command buttons are copied, but when i click button one it spits out a error and takes be to the code > Basically the worksheet name needs to be changed. Can someone help me in creating a code that will automatically work on all sheets when copied - i need around 35 sheets

My code is

```
Sub Changefontcolor()
'this code is the change font color in range of cells
'code start after this line'

Selection.Font.Color = vbRed

End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
'this code is the change front color in rage of cells
'code start after this line'

Worksheets("Audit Template").Range("K76:L92").Select
Selection.Font.Color = vbBlack


End Sub


Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
'this code is the change front color in rage of cells
'code start after this line'

Worksheets("Audit template").Range("K76:L92").Select
Selection.Font.Color = vbWhite
End Sub
```

Comment: If you want it to work on the sheet with the button just use a single line `Range("K76:L92").Font.Color = vbWhite`.

Comment: Thank you very much. All good to go now !

Answer (score 1):

### Trouble When Copying Sheets With Controls

**Any Sheet Code (Sheet1)**

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    RangeToBlack
End Sub
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
    RangeToWhite
End Sub
```

**Standard Module (Module1)**

```
Option Explicit

Public Const cRange As String = "K76:L92"

Sub ChangeToRed()
' change font color in any selected range to 'Red'
    Selection.Font.Color = vbRed
End Sub

Sub RangeToBlack()
' change font color in cRange to 'Black'
    ActiveSheet.Range(cRange).Font.Color = vbBlack
End Sub

Sub RangeToWhite()
' change font color in cRange to 'White'
    ActiveSheet.Range(cRange).Font.Color = vbWhite
End Sub
```

Now, if you change your mind about the colors or the range address, you can change it all in the module (in one place). As SJR commented, you can even remove "`ActiveSheet.`".